# Scrapy - Pytest execution not executing pipeline

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, pytest

I have this Scrapy project with its default structure and I added a test package with a test module.

So this is my structure:

```
scraping/
    scrapy.cfg 

    crawler/             
        __init__.py

        items.py         

        pipelines.py     

        settings.py      

        spiders/         
            __init__.py

            submissions_spider.py

        test/
            __init__.py

            test_request.py
```

First, before start testing with py.test framework, I just wrote a main function inside this module running a new CrawlerProcess that invokes my spider.

Something like this:

```
from scraping.crawler.spiders.submissions_spider import SubmissionsSpider
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

if __name__ == '__main__':
    crawler = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
    crawler.crawl(SubmissionsSpider, n=2)
    crawler.start()
```

This will execute perfectly on pycharm debugging. It runs my SubmissionsSpider and then process the items with my defined pipeline.

But... When I write a simple test just to execute the same routine above and run "py.test", the processing of the items with my pipeline is not executed. The process scrapes the data and nothing else.

This is my new test file:

```
import pytest
from scraping.crawler.spiders.submissions_spider import SubmissionsSpider
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from twisted.python.failure import Failure

@pytest.fixture
def crawler():
    return CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())

def test_crawler_execution(crawler):
    crawler.crawl(SubmissionsSpider, n=2)
    crawler.start()
```

I suspect it could be something in the configuration.

*scrapycfg file*:

```
[settings]
default = crawler.settings

[deploy]
#url = http://localhost:6800/
project = crawler
```

*settings.py*:

```
BOT_NAME = 'crawler'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['crawler.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'crawler.spiders'

ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True

ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'crawler.pipelines.MongoWriterPipeline': 1,
}
```

Any idea, folks?